# Finding the Maximum

Tags: function, matlab, wolfram-mathematica, analysis, max

How to find the following Maximum or supremum by computer software such as Mathematica and Matlab: `$\sup\frac{(1+s)^{4}+(s+t)^{4}+t^{4}}{1+s^{4}+t^{4}}$`?

Instead of numerical approximation, what is the accurate maximum?

Thanks.

Comment: You get an accurate (or analytic) solution by taking one derivative with respect to s and another derivative with respect to t, and then solving for where both of those derivatives are zero at the same time.

Comment: However, those derivative produce polynomials of order 7 in s and t, and generally no analytic solution is available. I suspect you should figure out some clever parameter substitution first. Assuming this is Homework, maybe you should think about what has been discussed in class.

Comment: @Timo in fact, the maximum for the function is one of the roots for a polynomial of order 27. I thought the problem was easier at first glance

Comment: I think, although it is clearly homework, we may provide some more guidance here if @user515055 shows some work done around @Timo suggestions above

Comment: If you plot the function there is and obvious substitution (s -> x - y, t -> x + y) which makes the maximum lie (unfortunately only almost) on the x-axis.

Comment: @Timo "almost" {t -> 1.0548407,  s -> 1.2752856}}

Comment: @Timo {t -> Root[
   1 + 3 s + 3 s^2 + s^3 - 3 s^4 - 3 s^5 - 
     s^6 + (3 s^2 - s^6) #1 + (3 s - 3 s^5) #1^2 + (1 - 
        3 s^4) #1^3 + (1 + 3 s + 3 s^2) #1^4 + 3 s^2 #1^5 + 
     3 s #1^6 + #1^7 &, 3]}

Comment: @belisarius, thanks. What does #1 mean?

Comment: @user515055 That was a comment addressed to @Timo, is not the actual solution. Please read the above comments by Timo, as the problem is not as straightforward as it seems. Anyway, just a warn, if you do not have any experience with Mathematica, you have to learn quite a few to solve it using this software.

Comment: @user515055  Don't hesitate to edit your question adding more on your findings, and we'll continue to support you.

Comment: @belisarius You're right, both s and t are roots are order 27 polynomials, as is the value of the actual maximum. It's not a nice problem. Do you know a nice way of approaching it?

Comment: @Simon That depends on what you call "nice" :). For max value of the function found also a 27th order poly, whose Root[p,1] is the max value. Was looking for some symmetry in the poly, but found none, so that was as far as I got: The poly, the root number and the numeric value. I did some work to "automate" finding the symbolic max value for a rational function of 2 vars for posting here as an answer, but as the asker dind't show any work, I am reluctant to post it here.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question seems a bit like homework, here's an answer that starts a bit like a lecture:

- ask yourself what happens to the function as `s` and `t` go to small and to large positive and negative values; this will help you to identify the range of values you should be examining; both *Mathematica* and *Matlab* can help your figure this out;
- draw the graph of your function over the range of values of interest, develop a feel for its shape and try to figure out where it has maxima; for this the *Mathematic* `Plot3D[]` function and the *Matlab* `plot()` function will both be useful;
- since this is a function of 2 variables, you should think about plotting some of its sections, ie hold `s` (or `t`) constant, and make a 2D plot of the section function;  again, develop some understanding of how the function behaves;
- now you should be able to do some kind of search of the `s,t` values around the maxima of the function and get an acceptably accurate result.

If this is too difficult then you could use the *Mathematica* function `NMaximize[]`.  I don't think that *Matlab* has the same functionality for symbolic functions built-in and you'll have to do the computations numerically but the function `findmax` will help.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Instead of numerically approximated maximum, what is or how to find the accurate maximum?

Comment: You would use Maximize[] in Mathematica for a symbolic solution, but NMaximize[] will produce an accurate maximum.

Comment: My computer is not powerful enough to get the value by using Maximize[] in Mathematica, no matter how long I wait for it computing the exact value, as I tried.

Comment: @belisarius: OP changed the question and is confusing accurate with symbolic.  I do my best but it's sometime just not good enough.  Sighhhh.

Comment: @High yep. Also Maximize can't cope with this one. You need (for example) to Solve the eq for one partial derivative first and then Maximize in one variable. That leads to the roots of a poly of order 27. Seems to me that the homework writer was a little sadistic.

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab, one would create a vector/matrix with s and t values, and a corresponding vector with the function values. Then you can pinpoint the maximum using the function `max`

In Mathematica, use `FindMaximum` like this:

```
f[s_,t_]:= ((1+s)^4 + (s+t)^4 + t^4)/(1+s^4+t^4)
FindMaximum[ f[s,t],{s,0},{t,0} ]
```

This searches for a maximum starting from (s,t)=(0,0).

For more info, see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindMaximum.html

Comment: `max`/`FindMaximum` give numerical approximation  in this case

Comment: @J-16 If you look at the timeline, you will see that this answer was posted BEFORE the OP asked _Instead of numerical approximation, what is the accurate maximum?_. So, If you've downvoted this answer, please reconsider it.