# Precision in Plots and in N[]

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a nice polynomial, which is in fact the non-posted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237694/finding-the-maximum) (I guess it is homework, so I'll post nothing until the asker shows some brain activity :D ):

```
jj = 1 + 54 #1 + 855 #1^2 + 6300 #1^3 + 37296 #1^4 + 221706 #1^5 + 
   385782 #1^6 + 1899783 #1^7 - 713709 #1^8 - 8772909 #1^9 + 
   1718343 #1^10 + 17264169 #1^11 - 3659847 #1^12 - 20026899 #1^13 + 
   3423276 #1^14 + 13768320 #1^15 - 1610712 #1^16 - 5314050 #1^17 + 
   881651 #1^18 + 1545093 #1^19 - 151263 #1^20 - 298626 #1^21 - 
   24552 #1^22 + 21978 #1^23 + 6594 #1^24 + 792 #1^25 + 
   45 #1^26 + #1^27 &
```

I want the first root. Just checking:

```
p[f_] := Plot[f[t], {t, Root[f, 1] - .003, Root[f, 1] + .003}];

p[jj]
```

[image]

Seems steep but good. But look now:

```
In[394]:= N[jj[Root[jj, 1]]]

Out[394]= -2.9523*10^13
```

If I ask for some precision:

```
In[396]:= N[jj[Root[jj, 1]], 1]

During evaluation of In[396]:= N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating 1+<<11>>+<<18>>. >>

Out[396]= 0.*10^-49
```

So the question is ... How different is the precision managing in Mma when you ask for a Plot and when you ask for a numeric result?

Comment: Plot uses machine numbers with no precision control whereas N increases working precision until it can guarantee target precision on the result. Stan Wagon has more details in chapter 1 of his book, like how to add precision control to Plot

Comment: BTW, Rob Knapp has a nice overview of precision handling in Mathematica http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7004/

Comment: @Yaro Thanks for the pointer! Bookmarked.

Comment: what is this wri-mathematica tag and why did you add it?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the mathematica tag?  I hope you are not suggesting using both tags on each post.

Comment: @Mr. I am trying to see if the initiative to change the [tag:mathematica] tag can get some momentum. Despite all efforts, some questions are being tagged as `mathematica` instead of `math`. I tried this matter previously on [meta](http://tinyurl.com/3ozdhpv) to no avail. I also proposed [tag:wri-mathematica] as a synonym for [tag:mathematica] [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mathematica/synonyms). Feel free to vote up this little initiative there if you think it fits.

Comment: @belisarius, I don't know how this works.  I would NOT want two tags in common use, and would prefer the existing "mathematica" tag to that.  However, if there is a process by which we can *change* the tag itself, without having to retag all the old questions, I can support that.  Looking at the synonyms page, it appears to me that if your new tag gets enough votes, it will automatically be replaced with "mathematica" -- surely that is not what you desire.  What is your plan?

Comment: @Mr. AFAIK the synonyms are not replacements, and ... I don't really have a plan. It all started when a few bigots tried to close several question in this tag believing they was math questions. And then I saw a lot of real math questions posted erroneously with the Mma tag. The idea is that if the tags are selected as synonyms, you could post a q in the wri-mma tag, and it will behave as a mma one (ie will appear in searches, etc) , but without the explicit [mma] leyend. So, nobody will try to close it.

Comment: I voted against your synonym, because I believe it is going to do exactly the opposite of what you want.  See:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work/70718#70718  "All uses of the synonym tag(s) for any given master tag are automatically converted to the master tag."  If it is your goal to replace the "mathematica" tag with the "wri-mathematica" tag, then you need to suggest "mathematica" as a synonym for "wri-mathematica" and not the other way around, as I understand the situation.

Comment: @Mr. Thanks. I'll re-read the whole thing again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is making a distinction between absolute and relative accuracy. Rant below, but first the solution:
According to the docs for `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal`, Mathematica will strive to return the result `x` with a numerical error less than `10^{-a} + 10^{-p} Abs[x]` where `a` is `AccuracyGoal` and `p` is `PrecisionGoal`. This causes a problem, if specifying a `PrecisionGoal` for a zero result. Solution: only specify `AccuracyGoal`.
For [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html) you do this by giving a `Precision,Accuracy` tupple:

```
In[113]:= N[jj[Root[jj,1]],{0,24}]
Out[113]= 0.*10^-24
```

<rant> The use of the terms "accuracy" and "precision" in Mathematica is very sloppy. They should really be called "absolute accuracy" and "relative accuracy". See e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) for a discussion of the correct terminology.</rant>

Comment: your <rant> pulled the trigger. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't think the computations performed by your plot command are anything like those performed by your N command.  You can check what points are plugged in during the plotting using Reap and Sow:

```
p[f_] := Plot[f[t], {t, Root[f, 1] - 0.003, Root[f, 1] + 0.003},
  EvaluationMonitor -> Sow[t]];
Reap[p[jj]][[2, 1]]
```

Notice that Plot uses only machine precision numbers.  This is very different from your N command, where you are plugging in the exact root of the function.  The difficulty with your arbitrary precision computation arises since you're trying to estimate an exact zero and Mathematica is unable to attach a precision to the result.  This can happen with much simpler polynomials.

```
x0 = x /. First[Solve[x^5 - x - 1 == 0, x]];
N[x0^5 - x0 - 1, 9]
```

Comment: +1 for the Reap[], Sow[] example ... never used that while plotting. I wonder what you mean by _"and Mathematica is unable to attach a precision to the result"_

Comment: Mathematica's arbitrary precision arithmetic attempts to attach a precision to each number. As Janus points out, Precision might be thought of as relative accuracy. Thus, if a number is accurate to +/-dx, its precision is based on dx/x. If x=0, this is not defined. This is related to the mathematical fact that you can't prove that an expression is exactly zero by simply using more digits. You can read much more on the topic by typing tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers into the Mathematica documentation center.

Answer (score -2):

The precision of the plot is just (approx.) the same as the graph size/resolution. This is an optimization in Mathematica.

Comment: Here's an example with 0 precision `Plot @@ {Normal[Series[Cos[x], {x, 0, 200}]], {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}}`